# discord.py how to find channel ID by channel name

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently programming a Discord Bot. I'm pretty new to the discord.py lib and I'm wondering how I can get the channel's ID by using the channel's name.

```
@bot.command
async def get_channel(ctx):
    global channel_id
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='willkommen')
    channel_id = channel.id
    print(channel_id)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    global channel_id
    willkommenssprüche = [f'➡ Mmmmmoin {member.mention}', f'➡ Moiiiiiin Meisteeer {member.mention}:100:', f'➡ Moin Leude, {member.mention} hier!', f'➡ Da biste ja {member.mention} alla!']
    
    
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(random.choice(willkommenssprüche))
```

that's my recent try ^

Thanks in advance, Frederik :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`discord.utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get).

```py
@client.command()
async def get_channel(ctx):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='channel name')
    print(channel.id)
```

If you are going to get the channel id in an `on_message` event, you can use `message.guild.channels` instead of `ctx.guild.channels`.

**EDIT**

You don't have to add the code that I've written. It's just an example. `on_member_join` has `member` parameter that has a `guild` attribute. So you can just use it.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    willkommenssprüche = [f'➡ Mmmmmoin {member.mention}', f'➡ Moiiiiiin Meisteeer {member.mention}:100:', f'➡ Moin Leude, {member.mention} hier!', f'➡ Da biste ja {member.mention} alla!']
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='willkommen')
    await channel.send(random.choice(willkommenssprüche))
```

Comment: I am currently trying to implement that im my code, but It doesn't work... Do you have Discord so that I can send you my code and you look at it? If you want :)

Comment: You should add the relevant part of your code to the question. It would be better.

Comment: Updated my post :)